# Unable to edit the /sys/block/sdX/device/queue_depth file

Tags: linux, ssd, block-device, scsi, sysfs

I'm trying to increase my SSD's queue depth value with the following command:

```
echo 64 > /sys/block/sda/device/queue_depth
```

But I receive the following error:

```
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

I tried using `tee` and even editors like `vim` and `nano` but still see this error. There are 4 SSDs on this server (sd[a-d]) and this error occurs for all of them.

OS is **CentOS 7** and kernel version is **3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64**.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your SSD does not support this queue depth?

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       M4-CT064M4SSD2                          
[...]
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
```

Alternatively, try with `1`, `2`, `3`, ... to find the maximum queue depth the kernel will allow you to use.

If it does not allow you to set values higher than `1`, maybe your kernel has NCQ disabled in general. Check `/proc/cmdline` for `libata.force=noncq` or similar.

There have been some NCQ related bugs, with SSDs in particular. You should do some benchmarks to check whether NCQ benefits you in any way at all and some tests whether (queued) TRIM works without corrupting data (current kernels fix these issues only by blacklisting some devices).